# Images pre-processing for convolutional neural network

Tags: image-processing, matrix, convolution

I have `*.png` files and I want to convert the images to one-hot encoding in the context of convolutional neural networks.

1. My images are `224x224`. I searched many online references, but I couldn't quite figure out how to convert an image into one-hot encoding. Do I append row by row or column by column? Is one way better than the other?
2. Once I create the one-hot encoded vector, normalization operations are applied, such as dividing each value of the vector by `256`(the max value of the RGB). This keeps the numbers from blowing up and causing overflow. However, I also see a `0.5` subtracted from this value. Why is this? This effectively puts the range of values between `[-0.5, 0.5]`. However, in most convnets, a `ReLU` layer is applied that will turn all these values to be zero or greater anyway. So, I'm confused on why this is done.
3. Lastly, once I convert the images into one-hot encoded vectors, where do I add the bias term? Do I add it in the front or in the back of the one-hot encoded vector and what exactly is this value supposed to be? Given normalization of the vector, I usually see the bias term being a `1` that is added to the front of the vector. However, why do we choose `1` and why is it usually appended to the front?

Comment: I think, I answered your question on stats stackexchange :) I am guessing you are getting mixed up because you are thinking of converting an image to onehot encoded representation. That is not how it works. One hot encoding is only about label, you won't need to convert the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think, I answered part of your question on stats stackexchange :) I am guessing you are getting mixed up because you are thinking of converting an image to onehot encoded representation. That is not how it works. One hot encoding is only about label, you won't need to convert the image (from my comment above)
2. Again as you are confused about one-hot(read up on it a little) you dont process one hot encoded label. you process the image(preprocess in this case). Normalisations can be of various types. For deep learning, the usual way is to normalize such that the mean is 0 and standard deviation is 1. I have not tried normalising with (-0.5, 0.5) but to answer your question on ReLU. ReLU is there to bring in non-linearity. It would be better if you read more about deep learning(back propagation especially.
3. Again! you have confused deep learning. Bias term is added during the training process. It is part of process. Since you are asking this question, you will need to read up on neural network.

This simple tutorial playlist helped me great deal to understand deep learning, hope this helps you too! Check it out [Neural network tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiaHhY2iBX9hdHaRr6b7XevZtgZRa1PoU)

Wish you good luck on learning :)

Comment: hmm, I see. Thank you! I'll look through it!